# Probability of two COVID-19 Tests with negative results - noninfected person

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

**Task:**

> A test for COVID-19 desease has probability for positive result from
> infected person equal to 0.9 and probability for negative result from
> noninfected person equal to 0.8. Half of the population is affected. What is the probability for a person
> to be noninfected if he has two negative tests? The tests are independent from one another.

**Solution:**

*Let:*

P - positive result

P' - negative result

I - infected person

I' - noninfected person

$P(P|I)=0.9$

$P(P'|I)=0.1$

$P(P'|I')=0.8$

$P(I)=0.5 => P(I')=0.5$

Probability for one negative test - using Bayes' theorem:

$$P(I'|P') = \frac{P(P'|I').P(I')}{P(P'|I').P(I') + P(P'|I).P(I)}$$
$$P(I'|P') = \frac{0,8.0,5}{0,8.0,5 + 0,1.0,5} = \frac{0,4}{0,4+0,05} = \frac{0,4}{0,45} = 0,8(8) ~= 0,89$$

How can I evaluate the probability of the person NOT being infected if he has TWO NEGATIVE tests?

Comment: What is the source of this question?  It was already asked a little while ago.

Comment: It was asked by me, sorry, I just got to this point and decided to ask another question instead of modifying the last one, as I know that it's not a good practice.

Comment: But you have not repaired either of the gaps that were pointed out to you before, so the question still can not be solved.  Just guessing that exactly half the population is infected isn't sensible.

Comment: I know that it isn't, but since it's not specified, the professor who assigned us the task said that we could guess or use 50%, whatever we choose. This solves the incidence in the population. As for the assumption of independence, we should assume that it's independent for the sake of this task. (of course, it's not like that in real life) What would be the approach if the test were independent and if they were not? Sorry for asking so many questions, I am struggling here.

Comment: If you want to make those assumptions you should add them to the post. If you want to assume independence, fine (though, again, add that to the statement of the problem).  Just work out, under the assumption of independence;  what's the probability that an infected person gets two negative results (out of two tests)?  Same question for an uninfected person.  Then just use Bayes in the ordinary way.

Comment: $0.8 \times 0.8 = 0.64$ chance that a non-infected person has two negative tests. $0.1 \times 0.1 = 0.01$ chance that an infected person has two negative tests. As infected and non-infected population is equal, the answer should be $ ~ \frac{0.64}{0.64+0.01}$

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as @lulu noted, you should add all of your assumption to your problem, not to solution!

Secondly, by assumption of **independency**:
$$       Prob(\text{NonInfected | 2 Negative})     =
     1 - Prob((\text{NonInfected | 2 Negative})^c) = $$
$$ = 1 - Prob(\text{Infected | 2 Negative})        = 
     1 - (Prob(\text{Infected | Negative}))^2      = $$
$$ = 1 - (0.89)^2 = 1 - 0.7921 = .02079              $$